# How to create a simple form to redirect the user to entered URL?

Tags: 7, forms, search, redirection

I want to create a simple form to redirect the visitors to a relative path they enter.

I created a search page with views and it has lots of exposed filters. I don't want to use this exposed filter as block.

On the main page I want to show only a simple search form and if the user enter a `word` then submit search button, it should redirect the user to `example.com/advanced-search?full_text=word`.

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a very simple method for this. I created a custom block and add this HTML code:

```
<form action="advanced-search" method="GET">
   <input type="search" name="full_text">
   <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Rules Forms Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms) module. Some more details about it (from its project page):

> Rules Forms Support provides a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) based method for controlling forms and their elements. The module can be used to alter any form provided by Drupal core or contributed modules. Change element titles, descriptions, weights, and more, or validate form data and set form errors. Rules forms saves time and cost by affording site builders the ability to monitor and alter forms without the need to implement a custom module.
>
> For help getting started with Rules Forms Support, please see the [module documentatio](https://www.drupal.org/node/1456178)n.
>
> Features
>
> - Activate events for form creation, validation, and submission on a form-by-form basis.
> - Target individual form elements or the entire form in conditions and actions.
> - Manipulate the attributes of a form element like title, description, weight, and more.
> - Validate the values of form elements during form validation.
> - Set form errors when rule-based validation fails.
> - Redirect users to a different page upon viewing or submitting a form.
> - Examine the attributes of elements in active forms with the element inspection tool.

Especially the "***Redirect users to a different page upon viewing or submitting a form***" should help to address your question.

Comment: Never heard of this module until now. `Rules forms saves time and cost by affording site builders the ability to monitor and alter forms without the need to implement a custom module.` Sounds like a very handy module to have.

Comment: Merci @NoSssweat ... So how many of the +17.000 do you think you have 'heard' about (my answer: maybe i heard about somewhere between 500 and 1.000 ...) ? That's what makes the job of a site builder, and/or site architect so interesting (I think) ... instead of digging in the (boring?) API docu, etc, right? FYI: my own very last "hidden gem" I discovered ... the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module ... another **K**eep**I**t-**S**uper**S**imple case IMO.

Comment: @ Pierre.Vriens wow, just wow!!! hidden gem indeed!

Comment: @NoSssweat : At the risk of running (soon) in "avoid extended discussions": if you didn't do so yet, go look at the module video ... Also be aware that "something" is in the pipeline about its maintainer-ship ... especially since it seems a perfect complement to the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module ... PS: there is even a [tag:goals] tag already around here ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I installed this module but unfortunately it's a bit useless. The settings of the module isn't in a single page, for every page reload it asks for something to enable. I will try to find another solution and if I can't I will try this module again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, sorry to hear it isn''t (yet?) what you are looking for. But can you add a few more details about that "*... for every page reload it asks for something to enable...*"?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, the module has a very simple settings page but there are other options on the fly and when you enable something this options are appear once and then disappear and not possible to find them again :)